# Load app.js file into jsdom

Tags: node.js, jsdom

I am using [jsdom](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom) to test my app.js file wit nodeJs.
  My `app.js` code looks like :

```
var appText = "hello"
```

I am trying to access this variable via jsdom as follow :

```
var appJs = fs.readFileSync("/absolute/path/to/app.js", "utf-8")

jsdom.env(
  "/path/to/index.html",
  [appJs],
  function (err, window) {
    console.log(window.appText)
  })
```

The variable `window.appText` prints the value `undefined` instead of `hello`.

Why is the `app.js` file not loaded, even though it is given as an args to `jsdom` func?

Answer (score 0):

The overload of jsdom.env you're trying to all expects a URL to the script file instead of the script source.

```
jsdom.env({
    url: "/path/to/index.html",
    src: [appJs],
    done: function (err, window) {
      console.log(window.appText)
    })
```

Comment: How do you do the equivalent using JSDom v11.0.0 ?